# node.js express multer issue uploading images to s3 using multer-s3 npm

Tags: node.js, express, multer, multer-s3

I have a problem uploading images to S3 using multer and multer-s3 npm with node.js and express.

I have read the documentation of multer and multer-s3 and followed the tutorials, and searched on stackoverflow and other websites to solve my issue but no success.

This is my client side code:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/test">
<p>
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="optional title"/>
</p>

<p>
    <input type="file" name="upl"/>
</p>

<p>
    <input type="submit"/>
</p>
</form>
```

And here is my server side code:

```
var express = require('express'),
 router = express.Router(),
 aws = require('aws-sdk'),
 multer = require('multer'),
 multerS3 = require('multer-s3'),
 s3 = new aws.S3()

 aws.config = ({
  secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
});

var upload = multer({
   storage: multerS3({
       s3: s3,
       bucket: 'styleboxphotosbianor',
       key: function (req, file, cb) {
         console.log(file);
         cb(null, file.originalname); //use Date.now() for unique file keys
      }
  })
});

//open in browser to see upload form
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.render('multer');
});

//use by upload form
router.post('/', upload.array('upl',1), function (req, res, next) {
  res.send("Uploaded!");
});

module.exports = router;
```

And I got this error

```
TypeError: this.s3.upload is not a function
at S3Storage.<anonymous> (/Users/magintosh/bianor/node_modules/multer-s3/index.js:150:26)
```

So i need your help my friends. Thank you a lot for being here for us!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must create "s3" variable only after setting up your "aws" module.
And also setting up the "aws" package should be with "aws.config.update"

```
var express = require('express'),
 router = express.Router(),
 aws = require('aws-sdk'),
 multer = require('multer'),
 multerS3 = require('multer-s3');

 aws.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
});

 s3 = new aws.S3();
```

*I assume that you replace the value for "secretAccessKey" and "accessKeyId" with actual key from AWS and you do have AWS account (some tutorial miss to mention that)

Comment: @Rajan .. how do i implement `ffmpeg` to convert a file and thn upload to `S3`?

Comment: @Somename I've never done that yet but the following question seems like a good starting point   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286798/nodejs-ffmpeg-sending-response-when-ffmpeg-is-completed  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227600/how-to-access-uploaded-file-from-multer

Comment: I've posted the second question with no luck so far. Could you please try and tell me ?